# unhandledRejection RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: wasm memory

Tags: node.js, next.js, out-of-memory, cpanel, prisma

When I build the Next JS site on the panel, I get this error and if you can help me

cpanel version:

```
Architecture : x86_64
operation system : linux
Perl Version : 5.26.3
Kernel Version: 4.18.0-372.16.1.lve.el8.x86_64
```

schema.prisma :

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["debian-openssl-3.0.x"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

Node.js version: 16.20.1

error:

```
unhandledRejection RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: wasm memory
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.